# Parsing line by line and matching numbers in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to create a program where I input my lottery numbers and match them against the lottery numbers provided by the lottery company. I want to read a docx file line by line and highlight the numbers that match on each line. I have tried to grapple with it. But so far have gotten no where. I have tried working out regex in ruby but haven't had much luck. I have been able to open and print out lines of a file, but not match any numbers.

[This is exactly what I want to build](http://rubular.com/r/N7uljBj9Os)

```
puts "What are your lotto numbers?"
numbers = gets.chomp
File.open("/Users/pcu/Documents/ruby/number.rtf").each do |line|
    if numbers[/(19|23/]
    puts "Has 19 or 23"
    end 
end
```

This is my totally wrong code. But I'm trying to get the numbers in a chomp. Turn that into a variable and use regex to find the matching numbers. Then I need to try and figure out how to match the numbers on the file to the chomp and then highlight each line on the file. Maybe even print out a file with the highlighted numbers.

Comment: Di you write any code?

Comment: I am not a programmer. I did write the basics of trying to get anything to work.

Comment: No problem. As long as you show that you already tried something, the community will be happy to help, regardless of your coding abilities.

Comment: you forgot to close the paren in your regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 separate problems :

- create a regex based on user input and use it to parse it a list of numbers
- read and write an RTF file.

## 1st step

To get an Array of winning numbers, you can use [`gets`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/Kernel.html#method-i-gets) followed by [scan](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/String.html#method-i-scan), to find every numbers in the string.

If you have an Array of winning numbers, you can use [`join('|')`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-join) to create a regexp. If you are sure that `3` is always written as `03` in the file, you can add one zero to every number if needed with [`rjust`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/String.html#method-i-rjust).

We add `\b` at the start and end of the regex, to make sure to match whole numbers only : `/23/` would match `123` otherwise. There shouldn't be any 3 digit number anyway, but it could still avoid some bugs.

You can then add a tick after each winning number with [gsub](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/String.html#method-i-gsub), and [sort](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by) your lines by how many ticks are present.

```
file_content = "18 19 37 21 39 29 39
22 33 83 29 92 03 12
83 74 56 29 34 94 92
94 72 57 65 38 85 95
18 26 37 28 39 29 39
22 33 83 29 92 03 12
83 74 56 29 34 94 92
94 72 57 65 38 85 95
18 26 37 28 39 29 39
22 33 83 29 92 03 12
83 74 56 29 34 94 92
94 72 57 65 38 85 95
18 26 37 28 39 29 39
22 33 83 29 92 03 12
83 74 56 29 34 94 92
94 72 57 65 38 85 95
18 26 37 28 39 29 39
22 33 83 29 92 03 12
83 74 56 29 34 94 92
94 72 57 65 38 85 95"

puts "Please input winning numbers, separated by a space. Example : 1 2 3 4 5 6 7"
numbers = gets.chomp.scan(/\d+/).map{|d| d.rjust(2,'0')}
puts

regex = /(\b#{numbers.join('|')}\b)/

puts file_content.gsub(regex,'\1✓').each_line.sort_by{|l| l.count('✓')}.reverse
```

It outputs :

```
18✓ 19✓ 37 21✓ 39✓ 29✓ 39✓
18✓ 26 37 28 39✓ 29✓ 39✓
18✓ 26 37 28 39✓ 29✓ 39✓
18✓ 26 37 28 39✓ 29✓ 39✓
18✓ 26 37 28 39✓ 29✓ 39✓
83 74 56 29✓ 34 94 92
22 33 83 29✓ 92 03 12
22 33 83 29✓ 92 03 12
83 74 56 29✓ 34 94 92
83 74 56 29✓ 34 94 92
22 33 83 29✓ 92 03 12
22 33 83 29✓ 92 03 12
83 74 56 29✓ 34 94 92
83 74 56 29✓ 34 94 92
22 33 83 29✓ 92 03 12
94 72 57 65 38 85 95
94 72 57 65 38 85 95
94 72 57 65 38 85 95
94 72 57 65 38 85 95
94 72 57 65 38 85 95
```

## 2nd step

If your code works fine with a text file, you can go on to tackle your second problem.

All the projects related to RTF seem to be pretty old, no idea if they still work. [Yomu](https://github.com/Erol/yomu) might.

For docx files, the project called [docx](https://github.com/chrahunt/docx) could help you.

As an alternative, you could write an HTML file, which Word also can read.

Comment: Is there a way to get the numbers from a docx file? File.open and then make that into a variable called file_content?

Comment: docx is a binary file. Try to open it with a basic text editor and you'll see why you cannot use `File.open`. You need some library for that. See update in my answer.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I'll look through all of this and learn a lot!